# How to merge two different type streams RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stream, rdd

I'm in the need of merging two different streams RDD.

Uno of the streams type is org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[String], and the other one is of type org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[twitter4j.Status].

I've tried:

```
  val streamRDD = stream.union(sentiments)
```

But it won't succeed:

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[String]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[twitter4j.Status]
[error]       val streamRDD = stream.union(sentiments)
[error]                                    ^
```

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? The error message correctly describes the problem: your `Dstream`s hold different types so can't be merged. What do you expect the resulting merged `DStream` to hold? If `String`  you'll have to convert the other into a `DStream[String]` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `union` only works on two `DStream` of the same element type, while you have `DStream[String]` and `DStream[twitter4j.Status]` and `String` is not `twitter4j.Status`.

I assume you have the following types:

```
val stream: DStream[twitter4j.Status]
val sentiments: DStream[String]
```

You have different choices to fix this:

- 1. You are sure that `String` and `twitter4j.Status` should be mixed into one `DStream` because they represent the same information in your context: convert either `DStream` to match the other

     - a) convert `stream` to match `sentiments`, so you need a conversion `twitter4j.Status => String`, possibly you can use `_.toString` like this:

       ```
       val stream2 = stream.map(_.toString)
       val result = stream2.union(sentiments)
       ```
     - b) convert `sentiments` to match `stream`, requiring `String => twitter4j.Status`.
- 2. `String` and `twitter4j.Status` are two different things in your context, you want to keep the distinction between both, but still combine them into one `DStream`

  In general you can use a `Sum`-type to represent each case, here we only have two so we can use the predefined `Either`:

  ```
  type R = DStream[Either[String,twitter4j.Status] // shorter
  val streamL: R = stream.map(Left(_))
  val sentimentR: R = sentiments.map(Right(_))
  val result: R = streamL.union(sentimentsR)
  ```

  At the end you will have **one** stream, where each element is either a `String` wrapped in a `Left` or a `twitter4j.Status` wrapped in a `Right`, allowing you to distinguish between the two when processing the stream.